# Can you use the sum formula for a geometric series starting at any point?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Wherever I see the sum of a infinite geometric series with $|r|<1$ being derived the series always starts at $n = 0$, or $n = 1$, the basic form is

$$a + ar + ar^2 + ar^3 + ... $$

And the sum is $\frac{a}{1-r}$

Does that still apply for a geometric series that starts at say n = 101, so

$$ar^{100} + ar^{101} + ar^{102} +... $$

Comment: Just factor out $r^{100}$ and there is your original form.

Comment: Your series is already in the "basic form". It is $b + br + br^2 + br^3 + \dots$, where $b = ar^{100}$

Answer (score 27):

\begin{align*}
ar^{100} + ar^{101} + ar^{102} +  \text{ ... } &= r^{100}\big[a + ar + ar^{2} + \text{ ... } \big] \\
&= \dfrac{ar^{100}}{1-r}
\end{align*}
So factoring out $r^{100}$, yes you have the same form.

Comment: I had always learned the formula as 'the first term over $1-r$.'  In that case you can start with any index.  I suppose your answer illustrates why this is true.

Answer (score 0):

I remember this by something a friend told me once. The sum of an infinite geometric series is the first term over one minus the common ratio. It is easier to remember without a formula I find.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think of it until now, but the numerator will always be the first term in the sequence you choose to start at.